# Are there JSDoc files for Firefox XPCOM?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, intellij-idea, xpcom, webstorm

While I know much of XPCOM is implemented in C++, it would still be great to have JavaScript stubs with empty functions, constants, and JSDoc. These could be used to support code completion, inspection, quick doc, and other features of IDEs like WebStorm (IntelliJ).

It would be great if this just existed somewhere (but I haven't found it). Another approach would be to try and generate them from the IDL, but I haven't found a a way to do that either. I have question on that at [Are there JSDoc files for Firefox XPCOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900549/are-there-jsdoc-files-for-firefox-xpcom).

Comment: It’s a shame that `xpidl` doesn’t know how to generate JavaScript stubs :(.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that a good ref. So yes, what I want is xpidl for JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [PHP script](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.pdt/plugins/org.eclipse.php.core/Resources/language/generate.php?view=co&root=Tools_Project) once, which generates PHP stubs from PHPDoc available at http://www.php.net for providing code assist in [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt). You can use similar approach to generate JSDoc from [XPCOM Doxygen](http://doxygen.db48x.net/mozilla-full/html/dir_e9857dacb2604f0c5b9ddf4ce2c1a90d.html).